# How to change single variable in Puppet between environments

Tags: ubuntu, puppet

Specifically, if I'm in staging, I want directory A, and in QA, directory B:

```
file{'/etc/appenv':
  ensure => file,
  owner  => 'root',
  group  => 'root',
  mode   => 0644,
  source => "file:///puppet/modules/myapp/appenv-${env}",
}
```

I have only 1 machine that needs this specific env for now. I have read [Puppet: variable overriding best practices](https://serverfault.com/questions/284259/puppet-variable-overriding-best-practices), but I thought stages were supposed to be used for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of ${env}, try using ${environment} as per the [official documentation](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/latest/env_environments.html).

If you want to change another variable based on the environment, you can do it in a conditional/case statement/selector:

```
$dir = ${environment} ? {
   'staging' =>'A',
    'QA' => 'B',
    default => 'unknown',
}

file{'/etc/appenv':
  ensure => file,
  owner  => 'root',
  group  => 'root',
  mode   => 0644,
  source => "file:///puppet/modules/myapp/${dir}/appenv",
}
```

Comment: I actually run puppet through cron jobs on my machines. Can I specify the environment without a puppet master or agent? I see `puppet agent --environment dev`, but what about `puppet apply --environment ... PATH/TO/MANIFEST.pp`? Can't see it on the manual page.

Comment: `puppet apply --environment=production` works fine. You can use any --option that you can put in the config file.

Comment: I also needed to remove the surround braces `${environment}` -> `$environment`